# Line elements on one line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get the search bar, date input with the calendar icon, and the search button all in line and centered in the div. So far I only got it centered in the div. But for some reason I can't get it in line and this happens:

[image]

```
<div class="input-group input-group-lg center">
            <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control searchbar" placeholder="Search for...">
              <div class="input-group date">
                <input type="text" class="form-control date" value="12-02-2012">
                <div class="input-group-addon calender-icon">
                  <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
              </div>

            <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-default search_icon" type="button"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            </span>
          </div>
```

and here is the css

```
.calender-icon {
  border-radius: 0px !important;
 }
.date {

  height: 50px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0px !important;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px !important;

}
.search_icon {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  height: 50px !important;
  width: 50px !important;
}


.searchbar {
  width:70%;
  margin: 20px 30px;
  height: 50px !important;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 30px !important;
  border-top-left-radius: 30px !important;

.center {
  margin: auto !important;
}
```

Not sure why this is happening. I've tried different styling and all failed, so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put "float: left;" into each specification, it should put them on the same line.

```
.calender-icon {
    float: left;
    ...
}
.date {
    float: left;
}
.searchbar {
    float: left;
    ...
}
...
```

Then, ensure .searchbar is closed properly with a closed curly brace.